# convergent subsequences etc.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

It is well known that:

> A sequence of real numbers converges $\{a_n\}$ to p, if and only if
>   every subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}$ converges to p.

I am wondering if this similar statement holds.:

> A sequence of real numbers $\{a_n\}$ converges to p if and only if
>   **every subsequence that does converge**, converges to p.

The $\rightarrow$ part follows from the first statement, it is the $\leftarrow$ part I have a problem with. I need to prove that:

> All subsequences that does converge, converges to p $\rightarrow$ the
>   main sequence converges to p.

Is this true?, also, does the answer depend on wheter we allow convergence to $-\infty,\infty$ or not?(I think I need to assume this, because it seems the statement is false if not, considering 1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,1,6,1,7......)

The problem I have with proving this, is that in the first statement we knew that all subsequences converges, and the main sequence is also a subsequence, so we are done, but now we do not know if the main sequence converges.

PS: I am assuming that atleast one subsequence converges, but I guess that if we include convergence to $-\infty,\infty$, this does not matter?

You do not need to give me the entire proof if you don't want, maybe only a hint if you know?(if the statement is true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is true. Consider the sequence $0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,...$ Any sub-sequence that converges must converge to $0$ but the sequence itself does not converge.

Edit: If we count $-\infty,\infty$ as possible limit points then I think this result is true. Suppose every subsequence that converges, converge to a point $x$. Look a subsequence that doesn't converge. If this subsequence goes to $-\infty,\infty$ then we have violated the assumption. Therefore, this subsequence must be bounded. Then by Bolzano Weierstrass Theorem, there must exist a convergent subsequence of this subsequence. This subsequence must converge to $x$. Next, recall that if a sequence in a bounded interval has exactly one limit point then that sequence must converge to that limit point. Therefore, the result follows.

Comment: If you include $+\infty$ then you have one subsequence that converges to $0$ and another that converges to $+\infty$, which arguably violates the OP's hypothesis.

Comment: Opps, I didn't see OP's edits.

Comment: Thank you, but there is one thing with the proof I have a question about. "If this subsequence goes to −∞,∞ then we have violated the assumption. Therefore, this subsequence must be bounded. ", even if the subsequence does not go to infinity or minus infinity, it may still be unbounded?

Comment: A sequence is either bounded or not bounded. If it is not bounded then it must go to $\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Comment: Opps, I mean if a sequence is unbounded then it must have a subsequence that converges to $\infty$ or $-\infty$

Comment: Thank you. I have one more question. You have shown that if you have an arbitrary subsequence, then there is a subsequence of this subsequence that converges, but this does not mean that the subsequence you started with converged?

Comment: We have proved that this subsequence must be bounded. So it must have at least 1 limit point. But since your original condition was that there is only 1 limit point for your original sequence, that means your new subsequence must have only 1 limit point. Then you use the "recall" part.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I see that it works now!:) Do you have any idea if x is infinity?

Comment: It should be similar but much easier argument.

Comment: Does this work you think? Let x be infinity, if the main sequence does not converge to infinity, then there exists an M, such that for each N, there is an $n_k > N$ such that $|a_{n_k}|<M$. This subsequence is bounded, so it must then have a convergent subsequence that converges to something else than infinity, so hence x can't be infinity?

Comment: This is not true. You can have $-1,1,-2,2,-3,3,-4,4,...$ Every subsequence converges to $\infty$ or $-\infty$

Comment: Yeah, but the hypothesis is that x is either -infinity, a finite number or + infinity, not two?

Comment: You said that if the main sequence does not converge to infinity then there must be a bounded subsequence. This is not true.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, thank you.

Comment: Maybe this works: Let x be infinity, either $a_n$ is bounded from below or not. If $a_n$ is bounded from below then all $a_n> -K$, assume now for contradiction that $a_n$ doe not converge to infinity, then we have that thre exists and M, such that for each N, there is an $n_k>N$ such that $-K<a_{n_k}<M$(I used the absolute value earlier, that was wrong). This subsequence is bounded, so it must have a convergent subsequence, converging to something else than infinity, this is a contradiction. Assume so that $a_n$ is not bounded from below, then it must have a subsequence converging to - inf

Comment: If a subsequence converges to - infinity, this is also a contraditcion for x beeing infinity.

Comment: Look correct to me!

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help and time. It was very smart and creative for you to come up with this strategy! Have a merry christmas!